# apply treats numbers as characters

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I couldn't find a solution for this problem online, as simple as it seems.
Here's it is:

```
#Construct test dataframe 
tf <- data.frame(1:3,4:6,c("A","A","A")) 

#Try the apply function I'm trying to use
test <- apply(tf,2,function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) mean(x) else unique(x)[1]) 

#Look at the output--all columns treated as character columns...
test

#Look at the format of the original data--the first two columns are integers. 
str(tf)
```

In general terms, I want to differentiate what function I `apply` over a row/column based on what type of data that row/column contains.

Here, I want a simple `mean` if the column is numeric and the first `unique` value if the column is a character column. As you can see, `apply` treats all columns as characters the way I've written this function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just write a specialised function and put it within `sapply`... don't use `apply(dtf, 2, fun)`. Besides, your character ain't so characterish as you may think - run `getOption("stringsAsFactors")` and see for yourself.

```
sapply(tf, class)
            X1.3             X4.6 c..A....A....A.. 
       "integer"        "integer"         "factor" 
sapply(tf, storage.mode)
            X1.3             X4.6 c..A....A....A.. 
       "integer"        "integer"        "integer"
```

***EDIT***

Or even better - use `lapply`:

```
fn <- function(x) {
  if(is.numeric(x) & !is.factor(x)) {
    mean(x)
  } else if (is.character(x)) {
    unique(x)[1]
  } else if (is.factor(x)) {
    as.character(x)[1]
  }
}

dtf <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 4:6, c = rep("A", 3), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dtf2 <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 4:6, c = rep("A", 3), stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

as.data.frame(lapply(dtf, fn))
  a b c
1 2 5 A
as.data.frame(lapply(dtf2, fn))
  a b c
1 2 5 A
```

Comment: This was exactly the answer--thanks! Cheers to everyone else who contributed :)

Comment: I forgot to add `stringsToFactors = FALSE`, since the class of column `c` defaults to `factor`. You may want to set `options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`, otherwise, you'll get a `factor`. Be advised.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use lapply() or sapply(), not apply(). A data.frame is a list under the hood, which apply will try to convert to a matrix before doing anything. Since at least one column in your data frame is character, every other column also gets coerced to character in forming that matrix.

Comment: That's right, matrix can hold only one type of data: `is.atomic(matrix())` yields `TRUE`

Answer (score 3):

I find the `numcolwise` and `catcolwise` functions from the `plyr` package useful here, for a syntactically simple solution:

First let's name the columns, to avoid ugly column names when doing the aggregation:

```
tf <- data.frame(a = 1:3,b=4:6, d = c("A","A","A"))
```

Then you get your desired result with this one-liner:

```
> cbind(numcolwise(mean)(tf), catcolwise( function(z) unique(z)[1] )(tf))
  a b d
1 2 5 A
```

Explanation: `numcolwise(f)` converts its argument ( in this case `f` is the `mean` function ) into a function that takes a data-frame and applies `f` only to the numeric columns of the data-frame. Similarly the `catcolwise` converts its function argument to a function that operates only on the categorical columns.